# software that shows a kind of “history” of actions or changes after opening a certain program

Tags: windows-10, monitoring

Ok, it's confusing, I hope I explained well. example: when a video game is started for the first time, a "saved games" folder is created somewhere in the /appdata folder. Then I want to know those changes, creations, file access, files are associated with it, etc. what that program does running in real time.

Sure, it's just an abstract example.

I currently use 'Process Hacker'. But it doesn't do this, not that I know of. thanks!